# Table lock after integrity maintanence completion

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

I am using SQL Server 2000. I have a database with n number of tables in it. I have configured a maintenance plan. If I enable integrity check and run the plan, I am not able to enter any data through VC++/ODBC.

Is there anything I have to check?

Comment: Integrity checks are normally run during maintenance windows (assuming you are not running 24/7).  Are you saying you can't enter data during the check OR after it completes?

Comment: After it completes; that too with the existing ODBC connection before the maintenance plan run. With a new connection, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll do yourself a service by reading [CHECKDB From Every Angle: Complete description of all CHECKDB stages](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/CHECKDB-From-Every-Angle-Complete-description-of-all-CHECKDB-stages.aspx) on Paul Randal's blog.

Specifically, locking happens in SQL 2000 during the **Non-clustered index cross-checks** portion of CHECKDB.

If you are unable to enter data AFTER the plan completes, you may have a database that is corrupt. I suggest reading the above blog, and run CHECKDB yourself in the Query Analyzer to monitor output.

Comment: Thanks. This happens only for a particular table in the Database.

Comment: What does your CHECKDB output look like? Is it clean?